# How to check with regex validator minimum characters without count whitespace

Tags: asp.net, regex

I mean like this

`"  T"` It's no 3 Character
`"T T"` It's no 3 Character
`" T "` It isn. 
`"TTT"` It's true
`" TTT"` is true
`" TT T"` is true

how to check that with regex

i'm trying `"^[\s]{3,100}$"` but it does'nt work

Thanks.

Comment: What do you want the answer to be for each one of the examples you gave?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you want to test for at least three non-whitespace characters. In which case this pattern should work.
`^\s*(\S\s*){3,100}$`

```
    [Test]
    public void Test()
    {
        Regex pattern = new Regex(@"^\s*(\S\s*){3,100}$");

        Assert.IsFalse(pattern.IsMatch(" T"));
        Assert.IsFalse(pattern.IsMatch("T T"));
        Assert.IsFalse(pattern.IsMatch(" TT"));
        Assert.IsTrue(pattern.IsMatch("TTT"));
        Assert.IsTrue(pattern.IsMatch(" TTT"));
    }
```

What isn't clear from your question is if white space is allowed or if the match should fail if any white space is present.

Comment: Thanks. but I'am try this  "    TTT" i'm type with 2 or more space in first it's not work, validator read not 3 characters entered. Thanks before

Comment: I've updated the pattern to allow a proceeding `\s*` to work with your  `" TTT"` scenario.

Answer (score 0):

I would say in Java because I am not familiar with asp.net (I am pretty sure you have lenght on String and replaceAll (regex, replacement) in asp.net as well):

```
System.out.println(input.length() == input.replaceAll("\\s", "").length());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex `/(\w)\1{2,}/` to match any character, followed by two or more of the same character like this in JavaScript: (you will have to translate to ASP.NET)

```
a = [" T ", "  T", "T  ", "TTT", "TTAT"]

for(i=0;i<a.length;i++)
  console.log(i, a[i], a[i].match(/(\w)\1{2,}/) != null)
```

Comment: Does this address "minimum characters without count whitespace" ?